# ASP.Net SessionState works when set to InProc but fails when set to StateServer

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

When allowing the SessionSate to remain in it's default state ie InProc, my website works fine after callbacks etc. When I change it to:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" timeout="10" />
```

SessionSate is lost after callback.

The ASP.Net State Server service is working fine so what else should I be checking?

Comment: Maybe there is an exception and the session state gets destroyed?

Comment: @wp78de I think you are close BUT I cannot get the details of the exception thrown because the exception is NOT created by the Server as Server.GetLastError() returns null. How do I debug the State Server?

Comment: Ensure all object you storing in the session has the [Serializable] decorator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were no issues in the code-behind however there was an issue with a popup window javascript which called localStorage to store session data. Once I removed the call to localStorage all worked fine.

Thanks to @wp78de for heading me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to get some debugging proxy (burp, charles,...)
- Check firewall rules

For more info look at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-asp/83f6b453-c695-419c-998b-0aa50279bc40

Comment: The firewall rules are OK. There is an error somewhere but in the Global.ApplicationError event, Server.GetLastError() returns null. The State Server is running according to TaskManager and the port etc is configured OK in web.config. Is it necessary to specify the port in the State Manager Service config somewhere?